# How to generate all combinations of letters and digits but in a specific format

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-loops, python-itertools, word-list

I'm trying to create a wordlist generator that creates a file with all possible combinations of uppercase letters and numbers but in this very specific format:

AAA00AA  (uppercase, uppercase, uppercase, digit, digit, uppercase, uppercase)

So the first string would be AAA00AA and the last one ZZZ99ZZ.
There are over 1 billion possible combinations and I'm using the `itertools.product` function.

However, I'm stuck on how to loop through the results of each iteration in order to get each group (AAA 00 AA) to combine among themselves. Here's what I got so far, but each loop runs just once. For example when the first group AAA 00 AA reaches ZZZ 00 AA I then need to get the second group through 1 iteration to AAA 01 AA and so on until the third group.

I'm sure that my loop nesting logic is wrong or perhaps I need to use some other approach, but I have no idea what to do. Can anyone help, please? Here's my code so far.

```
import string
import itertools
import datetime

letters = string.ascii_uppercase
digits = string.digits

first_group = itertools.product(letters, repeat=3)
second_group = itertools.product(digits, repeat=2)
third_group = itertools.product(letters, repeat=2)

FILE = open("mylist.txt","w")
start = datetime.datetime.now()

for i in first_group:
    first = ''.join(i)
    FILE.write(first + '\n')
    for a in second_group:
        second = first +''.join(a)
        FILE.write(second + '\n')
        for x in third_group:
            string = second +''.join(x)
            FILE.write(string + '\n')
            string = ''

FILE.close()
print 'DONE! - Finished in %s' % (datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to join the sub products again.

```
f, s, t = [
    itertools.product(d, repeat=r) 
    for d, r in zip([letters, digits, letters], [3, 2, 2])
]
with open("mylist.txt", "w") as f:
    for prod in itertools.product(f, s, t):
        string = ''.join([''.join(k) for k in prod])
        f.write(string + '\n')

# AAA00AA
# AAA00AB
# AAA00AC
# AAA00BA
# AAA00BB
# .......
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot @Coldspeed this is working beautifully now.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
import itertools
import datetime

letters = string.ascii_uppercase
digits = string.digits

first_group = itertools.product(letters, repeat=3)
second_group = itertools.product(digits, repeat=2)
third_group = itertools.product(letters, repeat=2)

start = datetime.datetime.now()

with open("mylist.txt","w") as FILE:
    for i in first_group:
        first = ''.join(i)
        for j in second_group:
            second = ''.join(j)
            for k in third_group:
                FILE.write(first + second + ''.join(k) + '\n')

print 'DONE! - Finished in %s' % (datetime.datetime.now() - start)
```

Generates:

> AAA00AA
>
> AAA00AB
>
> AAA00AC
>
> AAA00AD
>
> AAA00AE
>
> AAA00AF
>
> ...

Everything else you can leave as they are. the `itertools.product` solution by @Coldspeed is however more elegant and probably faster too. I just wanted to correct your code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, you're right it's better to use "with open()"

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```
res = ["".join(itertools.chain(a,b,c)) for c in third_group for b in second_group for a in first_group] 
res
['AAA00AA', 'AAB00AA', 'AAC00AA', 'AAD00AA', 'AAE00AA', 'AAF00AA', 'AAG00AA', 'AAH00AA', 'AAI00AA', 'AAJ00AA', 'AAK00AA', 'AAL00AA', 'AAM00AA', 'AAN00AA', 'AAO00AA', 'AAP00AA', 'AAQ00AA', 'AAR00AA', 'AAS00AA', 'AAT00AA', 'AAU00AA', 'AAV00AA', 'AAW00AA', 'AAX00AA', 'AAY00AA',...]
```

You can even make it a generator object:

```
for e in ("".join(itertools.chain(a,b,c)) for c in third_group for b in second_group for a in first_group):
    print e
```

Answer (score 0):

i am also facing kinda similar issue. I'm new to python too, i am generating a password combination of 6 letters like "AAAAAA" ends with "ZZZZZZ" with a few conditions, then puts it in a .txt file, when i run the code it takes a while then errors out MEMORYERROR. How can i make the code more efficient and less memory consuming. thanks here is the code

`from itertools import permutations from string import ascii_lowercase`

`def generate_password_combinations():`

```
# Define the valid letters for the password
valid_letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopgrstuvwxyz'

# Generate all permutations of the valid letters
permutations_list = permutations(valid_letters, 6)

# Filter out permutations that violate the repetition rule
filtered_permutations = []
for permutation in permutations_list:
    valid = True
    for i in range(len(permutation) - 2):
        if permutation[i] == permutation[i+1] and permutation[i] == permutation[i+2]:
            valid = False
            break
    if valid:
        filtered_permutations.append(permutation)

# Convert the permutations to uppercase strings
password_combinations = [''.join(perm).upper() for perm in filtered_permutations]

# Write the password combinations to a text document
with open('passwords_Combo1.txt', 'w') as file:
    for combination in password_combinations:
        file.write(combination + '\n')

return password_combinations
```

combinations = generate_password_combinations()
print(f"Generated {len(combinations)} password combinations.")
print("The combinations have been written to 'passwords_Combo1.txt'.")`

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35366884)